# Problem in accessing function of a class

Tags: php

Here is my index.php in this suppose i am calling the `command getresellers` it calls the `getresellers` function of `Reseller` class

```
$_command=$_REQUEST['_command'];
$dbs = new Databases();

switch($_command)
{
    case 'getresellerscount' :
        $rd=new Resellerdashboard($dbs);
        echo  $msg=$rd->getresellerscount();
        // echo Config::json_format($msg);
        // exit;
        break;
    case 'getresellers' :
        $rd=new Reseller($dbs);
        echo  $msg=$rd->getresellers();
        // echo Config::json_format($msg);
        // exit;
        break;
    default :
}

function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}
```

Here is my Reseller Class which want to call the ResellerDashBoard Class function But the error is coming

```
Class Reseller
 {
     private $dbs;

    public function __construct(Databases $dbs)
    {
        $this->dbs = $dbs;
    }
    /**
    *
    * function for getting resellers 
    *
    **/
    public function getresellers() 
    {
        list($fromdate,$todate)=ResellerDashBoard::getdate();
        $data_query="
            SELECT firstname,lastname,mobile,email,tmecode,tmename,updatedon,apptype,alloctype,empparent 
            from tbl_reseller_dashboard_intermediate 
            where empparent='".$_GET['city']."' ".$condition." 
                and updatedon>='".$_REQUEST['fromdate']." 00:00:00' and updatedon<='".$_REQUEST['todate']." 23:59:59' ";

        $result=$this->dbs->resellerdashboarddb->getResult($city);        



    }
 }
```

The error coming is

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include(ResellerDashBoard.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/abhijitnair/sandbox/newresellerdashboard/api/index.php</b> on line <b>38</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'ResellerDashBoard.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in <b>/home/abhijitnair/sandbox/newresellerdashboard/api/index.php</b> on line <b>38</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'ResellerDashBoard' not found in <b>/home/abhijitnair/sandbox/newresellerdashboard/api/Reseller.php</b> on line <b>45</b><br />
```

Please suggest what best should i do to access the Reseller DashBoard Function ?

Comment: First problem should be strikingly obvious. 
"include(ResellerDashBoard.php) failed to open stream: No such file or directory"... Ensure that the files are where they should be... in your current working directory, or specify a full filepath in your autoloader

Comment: Then check that the current working directory is that folder using getcwd()... the error message you're getting is very explicit

Comment: Checked it is the same `api` directory .

Comment: Just because the a file is included from another file in the same directory, doesn't mean that the current working directory is that directory. Use getcwd() to check. Failing that, check file permissions/privileges.

Comment: @Mark you are right please right the answer i will accept it .

Comment: The file name or class name i write wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem should be strikingly obvious. "include(ResellerDashBoard.php) failed to open stream: No such file or directory"... Ensure that the files are where they should be... in your current working directory, or specify a full filepath in your autoloader.

Then check that the current working directory is that folder using getcwd()

Failing that, check file permissions/privileges.